# GROUP_Concat Hyperlink <a>

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have in my database a table called `"Clients"` and an other one called `"Pets"`. They are linked by an associative table which means that a `"Clients"` can have two "Pets".

I am using this SQL Query to display many pets for one client :

```
SELECT *, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT petName ORDER BY petName) AS petsNames
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN owners ON owners.idClients = clients.idClients
LEFT JOIN pets ON pets.idPets = owners.idPets
LEFT JOIN clientsdocs ON clientsdocs.idClients = clients.idClients
WHERE clients.idClients='$id'
```

And I am using this foreach loop :

```
foreach ($files as $file) :
echo $file['address'];
endforeach
```

My issue is the following :

```
<strong>Pets : </strong> <a href="?profilePet=<?= $file['idPets']; ?>"> <strong><?= $file['petsNames']; ?> </strong> </a>
```

I am using this line of code to print the client's pets but I want them to be hyperlinked, Which means that I would be able to Click on the differents pets. The problem is that GROUP_Concat linked all of the pets which mean that when I click on one pet I always go to the first written.

[image]

As you can see, the pet "Penelope" and "W" are linked by "`GROUP_COncat"`. So when I click on it, it sends me to the first pet (Penelope).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh I am using  PHPMYADMIN, InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

You can split your petnames about comma and add `a` tags to each of it :

```
$pets = explode(',',$file['petsNames']);
foreach($pets as $pet){
echo '<a>'.$pet.'</a>';
}
```